# how can i make a split that ignore what inside quotes or d_quotes in c?

Tags: c, algorithm

i recode a split that split between every separator, i want to modify it to ignore what s inside double or single quotes but i couldn't

i try to use a flag but it was very complicated if it succeed in a test it fail in others
this is my code i was trying alot,  if someone have a better algo or already recode it in that way

```
void    quote_state(char c , int *inquotes) // checking quotes state
{
    if (c == '\'' || c == '\"')
    {
        if(!(*inquotes))
            *inquotes = 1;
        else if (*inquotes == 1)
            *inquotes = 0;
    }
}

char    **ft_split2(char *s, char c)
{
    char **str;
    int    i;
    int    j;
    int start;
    int    inquotes;

    // allocating exactly what i need
    //...

    while (s[j])
    {
        while (s[j] == c && !inquotes)
            j++;
        start = j;
        quote_state(s[j], &inquotes);
        while (s[j] != c && s[j])
        {
            quote_state(s[j], &inquotes);
            j++;
            if (inquotes)
                break;
        }
        if ((s[j] == "\"" || s[j] == "\'") && inquotes)
            j++;
        if (j > start)
            str[i++] = wordp(s, start, j); // allocating and placing elements .. 
    }
    str[i] = NULL
    return(str);
}
```

the input was : " kaka koko " waah waah " lla  "

this is the output : kaka\0koko\0"\0waah waah "\0lla\0

but i want the output to be : kaka\0koko\0" waah waah "\0lla\0NULL

Comment: i was debugging for 3 days xd, i wouldnt ask if i wasnt really stucked

Comment: @Omar Jebbari What about these strings "\"", "\"\'", "\"A", "A\""? What should the function return?

Comment: @Omar Jebbari, Improve question. Post a [mcve].  Consider using more meaningful object names than `c`, `x`, ...

Comment: @vladfromMoscow it s hard to tell u the example is relatively wrong , becauze u use some " without \ so it mean that u give the function more than a string , but the function takes just a string

Comment: @OmarJebbari I showed correct C strings. Investigate them anew.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica as i understand from reading the minimal reproducible example that i write alot and this is complicated for the viewers , so i develop and edited the post a little , it s my 1st question in stackoverflow that's why , thanks for the comment it s developp the community

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , int the main the char *p cant take p[] = "A" "B";  but he can take "A\" \"B";    once u open a double quote u can close it just once as " but u can give it " as \" did u understand what i m trying to say ?

Comment: @OmarJebbari Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.  Posted code has at least 3 and 1 error.

Comment: @OmarJebbari I have not understood how this  p[] = "A" "B"; is related to the strings I showed. For example "\"" is a correct C string.

Comment: @OmarJebbari the strings from VladfromMoscow aren't one big string, but different strings : `"\""`, `"\"\'"`, `"\"A"`, `"A\""`

Answer (score 1):

```
        if ((s[j] == "\"" || s[j] == "\'") && inquotes)
```

Can you see something incorrect about this line, that could produce undefined behavior?

Comment: that line was a hard coded part, yeah it is an undefinded behavior, in general I put the code just bcz the rules ask me to put it i know it s wrong, want to know if there is a known algo i can use for this problem

Comment: What I was getting at was, you're comparing a char to a string. Twice. This is a very easy fix.

Comment: yeah but it works normaly , u want to say that it should be '\'' || '\"' ? but Although I am using it in double quotes it works

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I'm glad it worked this time, but I wouldn't recommend that you depend on it.